# Storing array in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to store IMDB's database in postgresql (https://www.imdb.com/interfaces/) but I'm running into some problems.

```
CREATE TABLE akas(
  titleID VARCHAR, 
  ordering INTEGER, 
  title VARCHAR, 
  region VARCHAR, 
  language VARCHAR, 
  types text[], 
  attributes text[], 
  isOriginalTitle BOOLEAN
);
```

The attributes column and types column is supposed to take an array of values. When I read from my tsv- file:

```
COPY akas FROM '/pathtofile/title_akas_transformed.tsv' DELIMITER E'\t' NULL '\N' CSV HEADER;
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  malformed array literal: "imdbDisplay"

DETAIL:  Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.
```

Do anybody know how to solve this?

The tsv-file I'm reading from is (I've made it smaller so it is easier to work with):

```
titleId ordering    title   region  language    types   attributes  isOriginalTitle
tt0000001   1   Карменсіта  UA  \N  imdbDisplay \N  0
tt0000001   2   Carmencita  DE  \N  \N  literal title   0
tt0000001   3   Carmencita - spanyol tánc   HU  \N  imdbDisplay \N  0
tt0000001   4   Καρμενσίτα  GR  \N  imdbDisplay \N  0
tt0000001   5   Карменсита  RU  \N  imdbDisplay \N  0
tt0000001   6   Carmencita  US  \N  \N  \N  0
tt0000001   7   Carmencita  \N  \N  original    \N  1
tt0000001   8   カルメンチータ JP  ja  imdbDisplay \N  0
tt0000002   1   Le clown et ses chiens  \N  \N  original    \N  1
tt0000002   2   A bohóc és kutyái   HU  \N  imdbDisplay \N  0
tt0000002   3   Le clown et ses chiens  FR  \N  \N  \N  0
tt0000002   4   Der Clown und seine Hunde   DE  \N  \N  literal title   0
tt0000002   5   Clovnul si cainii sai   RO  \N  imdbDisplay \N  0
tt0000002   6   Клоун и его собаки  RU  \N  imdbDisplay \N  0
tt0000002   7   The Clown and His Dogs  US  \N  \N  literal English title   0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`imdbDisplay` or `literal English title` are not valid literals of type `text[]`.
The latter would have to look like

```
{literal English title}
```

or

```
{literal,English,title}
```

depending on whether it is an array with one or three elements.

If you cannot change the file to the correct format, you will have to create a temporary table that use type `text` rather than the array columns, `COPY` the file into the temporary table and do something like

```
INSERT INTO akas
SELECT titleid,
       ordering,
       title,
       region,
       language,
       ARRAY[types],
       ARRAY[attributes],
       isoriginaltitle
FROM temptable;
```

This example assumes that the string is a single array element, otherwise you will have to use a function like `regexp_split_to_array`.

Comment: {"\\N"}
 {"literal title"}
 {"\\N"}
 {"\\N"}
 {"\\N"}
 {"\\N"}
 {"\\N"}
 {"\\N"}
 {"\\N"}
 {"\\N"}
 {"\\N"}
 {"literal title"}
 {"\\N"}
 {"\\N"}
 {"literal English title"}

This looks correct now, right? :)

Comment: No. Only use the braces with those columns that are arrays.

Comment: Yes, but types and attributes are supposed to be arrays, and I store every element as an array. Do you mean that "literal english title" is supposed to be {literal, english, title} or what? In my temptable table I store types and attributes as TEXT and then use ARRAY[types], ARRAY[attributes] in my akas table.

Comment: That depends on whether it should be a single array element or three. Taking a step back: why do you want `text[]` and not `text`?

Comment: Well, my big problem is that I don't quite get how I'm supposed to store it, on imdb's site they just say that the data type is an array. I've changed my types and attributes in akas to TEXT now.

Comment: That makes much more sense.